# Springboot 3 and GraphQL compatibility

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, spring-graphql

I am upgrading my spring boot application from 2.1.6.RELEASE to 3.0.0
After resolving all the errors, the graphql apis are returning null and even the breakpoints are not getting triggered in any of the classes.

Does Spring boot 3 have support for GraphQL?

The following post kind of indicates that the support is not available but need some confirmation.
https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/22/spring-for-graphql-1-0-3-released

Comment: Yes, just use the Spring Boot Graphql starter : https://spring.io/projects/spring-graphql. I use it with Spring Boot 3.0.0 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Upgrade to Spring Boot 3 and Java 17

Migrated to spring boot version 3.0.0 from 2.1.6.RELEASE
Migrated to Java 17 from Java 8
Removed GraphQLQueryResolver and GraphQLMutationResolver -  as they were not working
Used the following instead:
    Added @QueryMapping and @MutationMapping
    Changed Query and Mutation classes from @Component to @Controller
    Added jakarta.persistence-api dependency
    @Argument keyword added to the parameters in functions

Used the following dependency
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: would you be able to provide more information on what was used to replace GraphQLQueryResolver? I believe a @Schema Mapping could be used to replace functionality, confirmation would be helpful

Comment: This was a tremendous help!  Documentation for SprintBoot 3.x with GraphQL is practically nonexistent.

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Boot 2.7.x, the Spring team released the new [Spring GraphQL project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-graphql). This is also currently supported with Spring Boot 3.0.

If you were using GraphQL support with Spring Boot 2.1.x, this means that your application is using a different project for GraphQL support. Could you share the name of the dependency you're using? Maybe this project is not yet compatible with Spring Boot 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Spring boot 3.0.1`. It's fixed in 3.0.1 version